# Parse Core Pointer type Relations in ParseDb GAS library

Tags: google-apps-script, parse-platform

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to run a daily job which modifies a Parse Core database.

I would like to query a table based on a field which points to a particular User.

In the Parse Javascript library, this is no trouble, but the ParseDb library is designed to work the same as the old ScriptDb library (which I have never used)... and looking through the old documentation of ScriptDb, there doesn't seem to be much information about this sort of case.

Simply passing the user object to a query doesn't really seem to help. It simply throws up an error in the logs which says that ParseDb was expecting a pointer type, but there is little information anywhere on how to actually get a pointer type... I tried passing the user Id (using `.getId()`), and that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has a REST API that you could use with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` to send HTTP requests to Parse.

[Parse Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#summary)

In the Quick Reference, there is an explanation of the Request Format:

[Parse - Quick Reference](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#general-quick)

> All API access is over HTTPS, and accessed via the
>   https://api.parse.com domain. The relative path prefix /1/ indicates
>   that we are currently using version 1 of the API.

To retrieve objects you need to configure the URL with:

```
/1/classes/<className>/<objectId>
```

So, the URL would be:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/<className>/<objectId>
```

You would put that URL into the URL parameter of `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, optional parameters)`.

[Google Documentation - UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

To do data queries, you can use a "**where**" URL parameter:

```
'where={"playerName":"Players Name","cheatMode":false}'
```

[Parse Documentation - Query Constraints](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints)

I'm not sure how this is used.  It seems like it's a URL Search string parameter.
I'm guessing that it is the same as:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/<className>/<objectId>?where={"playerName":"Players Name","cheatMode":false}
```

### UrlFetchApp

```
var options = {method:GET};

var theUrl = https://api.parse.com/1/classes/<className>/<objectId>;
var whereQuery = "?where={"playerName":"Players Name","cheatMode":false}";

UrlFetchApp.fetch(theUrl + whereQuery, options);
```

I haven't tested this, so you may need to make some changes, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Okay, so I got this working okay... but I can't seem to figure out how to send the queries using UrlFetchApp... I'm probably just being stupid, but I can't see anything about querystrings in the Documentation. There is "Payload" but it says that GET does not use Payload...

Comment: Ahh, Now I think I have another problem. The ACL on each item in the class is set to the associated User. As a result, these REST API calls are returning empty results. I guess I need to set it to something else. Or authenticate the user...?

Comment: Yah, you'll probably need to run an authentication before querying the data.  You can assign the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` to a variable, and then check what gets returned.  Also, step through in debug to figure out what's going on.  [Apps Script Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)